# How make a character climb rocks and blocks in the BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, workflow

I am trying to do something like that image below... But no more ideas...

[image: jump climb move]

It's for a semi-platformer game that uses simple jumps, this grab ledge above and some other. I already know how to do a vertical stair, but this is braking my mind.

Comment: Your question is too general - this is not a place for teaching you how to do a character animation. I think we can only give you an advice to watch some tutorials on how to animate and start with some more easier tasks first. Then if you have some problems with using the Blender, we can help you here.

Comment: yeah, i was too general... my question isn't about animation... I am trying do a cube act like the image. There's a video that teaches how to do a climb stairs (vertical)... My wish is to do anything like, but with jump, and after grab like magnetic pieces.
After this, doing anything to stay above the block.

Comment: Thanks... I am now understanding what i am doing wrong... it's only all... I'm not doing animations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've get a satisfatory answer to my problem working only in **expressions and logick bricks.**
In fact, I was searching a system that make me get a cube or anything to climb other object for after do the animations and etc.

Today i've found a way to allow me to do a wall climb with one cube to other object.

[image]

The way I use was:
Named any properties to my cube that is my personage.

1. Called a property "climbable" to the object that you want you personage climb.
2. link colision "obst" and property "parede" to the actuators edit object "supende" and property "escalaS" using the controller expression with "obst AND NOT parede"
3. link the sensors: Keyboard W and property "parede" to the actuator motion "cima"

**explain:**

- colision "obst" is to test the colision between personage and object.
- property "parede" is to verify true to the property "climbable" in the personage.
- edit object named "suspende" is to suspend the dynamics. Actuator edit mode, set to dynamics -> suspend (that is the trick on newer blenders. Cause it turns any object into a static one with no colision rules).
- property "escalaS" is to set property from persnagem to a climbable one (this do easy to me to treat the others problems.)
- The actuator motion "cima" is to move up the actually static object.

**Then you'll ask me: and to turn it dynamic again?
Do yours links in the better way you find and link actuators:**

- property climbable assign False and
- edit object dynamics restore

These last 2 do the cube works like a personage or character again.
Now is time to work in the animations then throw in the cube and do my game.

I hope this helps anyone.

p.s.: I've used names like suspende, cima, parede and others no english cause i'm brazilian. And here we talk brazilian portuguese. If have any or many errors in this text correct me. I'll thank you.

Comment: doesn't work on blender. Only in the UPBGE ;-;
In blender looks like nothings has made. I'm working on windows 10 64 bits